# How to Play a RealAudio (.RA) File (Remote or Local) in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, audio, audio-streaming

I need to be able to play a RealAudio (.RA) file from Xcode. If i cannot play the file directly from the URL, it is ok if i can download it and play.  Primary help i am looking for his how to Play RealNetworks RealAudio (.RA) file in Xcode 4.3 under iOS5.0.

Comment: VLC Player is open source and had their libraries up, but the app was pulled from the app store. They have real audio support, but that only works today with Jailbroken devices. If you're requirements allow to download, could you pass it through a service to convert it to a MP3 so that you can just use the built in audio services?

Comment: Digicoder, i only see MacOSX code at http://wiki.videolan.org/GetTheSource#Latest_Source no iphone sample code.  Let me know if i am looking at the wrong location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across an iOS package for playing Real Audio files, however, iOS does support some of the [RealAudio Codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealAudio#Codecs). Specifically, it should be able to play the audio streams from RA files encoded with the raac and racp codecs. iOS won't know what to do with the RealAudio container, so you will have to determine what needs to happen to extract the audio stream from the file. [This website](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=RealMedia) contains details about the container.